# Custom favicon for bookmarklet

Tags: favicon, bookmarklet, bookmarks

Does anyone know of a workaround/trick to automatically set a custom favicon for a bookmarklet? I know it's possible for the user to change the favicon manually, but I want to be able to have it set automatically either when the bookmarklet is dragged to the bookmark bar or, perhaps, after the user first clicks the bookmarklet in the bookmark bar.